# (C#) How to Write a Line at the end of a Text Document?

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on an index.html Editor. Everything has to be Written to the end of the Document, so all tags can be closed correctly. I have no idea what I can do so there is no example. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Can you share a sample image of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method in `System.IO` class `File`

```
public static void AppendAllText (string path, string? contents);
```

It's been in .Net since Framework 3.5 (and possibly earlier)